# what are the options other than query string to pass large amount of data between pages situated at different servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, query-string

One of my client has two servers. One is asp.net enabled while other server is just static.
On the static servers there are just html files.
Now the client want to have a page for maling on static server.
since there is no server side script available on static server I created a page in html which on submission uses javascript to  create  a querystring with the fields submitted.
this querystring is passed to the aspx page situated on different server where user is asked for username and password.

Everything is going fine but when the data is large then the querystring get ignored. Since there is no upperlimit for the data that a user can submit in one go , 90% of the times i get an error.

I have included the following line in web.config but got no success.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" executionTimeout="32768"/>
```

Are there any other way to pass data over servers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post data via request url is a good option, here is an example

http://andreaazzola.com/post/post-data-js

Answer (score 0):

You can send a post request instead, and post your data in a form field.

Comment: Can you give more detail/links?

Comment: also i am opening that page as modal popup as just giving its location with querystring